# Radio button .prop (checked true) but not tick showed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am creating a modal form in php, which contains the following radio button.

This is my php form:

```
<div class="form-group">
              <div class="form-row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="panel"><strong>PRIORIDAD</strong> </div>
                <div class='form-check form-check-inline'>
                <input type="radio" id="prioridadtrivial" name="prioridad" class="prioridad" value="TRIVIAL" > TRIVIAL<br/>
                <input type="radio" id="prioridadtolerable" name="prioridad" class="prioridad" value="TOLERABLE" > TOLERABLE<br/>
                <input type="radio" id="prioridadmoderada" name="prioridad" class="prioridad" value="MODERADA" > MODERADA<br/>
                <input type="radio" id="prioridadimportante" name="prioridad" class="prioridad" value="IMPORTANTE" > IMPORTANTE<br/>
                <input type="text" id="prioridadtext" name="prioridadtext" class="form-control input prioridadtext" value="" >
                </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
```

After a call ajax, I get the value of the input type ="text" id="prioridadtext" and based in this value I want to check the radio with the same value.

And this is my js script:

```
var priority = $("#modalEditarProducto .prioridadtext").val(respuesta[0]["prioridad"]);
        //alert(prioridad[0].value);
        
        
        console.log('priority vale: ' + priority[0].value);

        if(priority[0].value == "TRIVIAL"){
            alert($('input:radio[name=prioridad]#prioridadtrivial').val());
            $('input:radio[name=prioridad]#prioridadtrivial').prop('checked',true);
            
            
        }else if(priority[0].value == 'TOLERABLE'){
            alert($('input:radio[name=prioridad]#prioridadtolerable').val());
            $('input:radio[name=prioridad]#prioridadtolerable').prop('checked',true);
        
        }else if(priority[0].value == 'MODERADA'){
            alert($('input:radio[name=prioridad]#prioridadmoderada').val());
            $('input:radio[name=prioridad]#prioridadmoderada').prop('checked',true);
            
        }else if(priority[0].value == 'IMPORTANTE'){
            alert($('input:radio[name=prioridad]#prioridadimportante').val());
            $('input:radio[name=prioridad]#prioridadimportante').prop('checked',true);
            
        }
```

The problem is that I can't display the correct radio ticked.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJEi1.png)

Any help please?

Comment: priority[0] 2 times, and just priority 2 times?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Comment: you are right, but the reason is because I was trying differents options whitout success.

Answer (score 0):

`priority` is a jQuery object so you need to retrieve the `value` from the element within it using either `val()` or `[0].value` and compare that to the object property, not the jQuery object itself.

Also, ensure that you execute this logic ***after*** the AJAX call, which I assume retrieves the data in `respuesta`, has completed.

Here's a working version with the logic tidied a little - note that as you're using an `id` selector to target the radio buttons that's all you need to use. As ids are unique anything more than that, such as the tag name and attribute selectors, are redundant.

```js
let respuesta = [{
  prioridad: "TOLERABLE"
}];

var $priority = $("#modalEditarProducto .prioridadtext").val(respuesta[0]["prioridad"]);
if ($priority.val() == "TRIVIAL") {
  $('#prioridadtrivial').prop('checked', true);
} else if ($priority.val() == 'TOLERABLE') {
  $('#prioridadtolerable').prop('checked', true);
} else if ($priority.val() == 'MODERADA') {
  $('#prioridadmoderada').prop('checked', true);
} else if ($priority.val() == 'IMPORTANTE') {
  $('#prioridadimportante').prop('checked', true);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="modalEditarProducto">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="panel"><strong>PRIORIDAD</strong> </div>
        <div class='form-check form-check-inline'>
          <input type="radio" id="prioridadtrivial" name="prioridad" class="prioridad" value="TRIVIAL"> TRIVIAL<br/>
          <input type="radio" id="prioridadtolerable" name="prioridad" class="prioridad" value="TOLERABLE"> TOLERABLE<br/>
          <input type="radio" id="prioridadmoderada" name="prioridad" class="prioridad" value="MODERADA"> MODERADA<br/>
          <input type="radio" id="prioridadimportante" name="prioridad" class="prioridad" value="IMPORTANTE"> IMPORTANTE<br/>
          <input type="text" id="prioridadtext" name="prioridadtext" class="form-control input prioridadtext" value="" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

There is also this slightly more succinct alternative to your entire `if` block, but it's a little brittle:

```
$(`#prioridad${$priority.val().toLowerCase()}`).prop('checked', true);
```

Comment: Thank you @Rory McCrossan for your comment, but it's still not working. I am using AdminLTE template. Could this be related to this issue? Thanks